# Замените прямую речь косвенной

Tags: грамматика

Замените прямую речь косвенной. Я делала правда или нет помогите пожалуста ?
Вопросы

1. Друг спросил меня: «Что ты делал вчера вечером?» Я ответил: «Вчера вечером я ходил в кино». 2. Преподаватель сообщил нам: «Послезавтра у вас будет контрольная работа». Мы спросили: «Контрольная работа будет трудная?»
2. «Какую книгу ты читаешь?» — поинтересовался товарищ. «Я читаю роман Шолохова», — ответил я.
3. «Почему ты так спешишь», — удивился мой друг. «Спешу, потому что опаздываю в театр», — объяснил я ему.
4. «Как пройти к станции метро?» — спросил меня на улице незнакомый мужчина. Я сказал ему: «Идите прямо, потом налево».
5. «Ты скоро пойдѐшь обедать?» — спросила меня Таня. «Я пойду обедать через час», — ответил я.
6. «Посмотри новый фильм», — посоветовал мне мой друг.
7. «С кем ты ходил вчера на стадион?» — спросил меня брат.
8. «Принеси мне из аптеки лекарство», — попросил больной студент своего товарища.
9. «Я должен кончить эту работу сегодня», — решил Володя.
10. В письме брат написал мне: «Купи и пришли мне новые марки».

Ответы

1. Друг спросил его о том, что он делал вчера вечером. Он ответил, что вчера вечером ходил в кино.
2. Преподаватель сообщил им, что послезавтра у них будет контрольная работа. Они спросили его о том, будет ли контрольная работа трудная.

3.Товарищ поинтересовался у него о том, какую книгу он читает. Он ответил, что читает Роман Шолохова.

4.Его друг удивился и спросил почему он так спешил. Он объяснил ему, что спешит, потому что опаздывает в театр.

5.Незнакомый мужчина на улице спросил его о том, как пройти к станции метро. Он сказал ему идти прямо, потом налево.

6.Таня спросила его о том, скоро ли он пойдет обедать. Он ответил, что пойдет обедать через час.

7. Его друг посоветовал ему посмотреть новый фильм.
8. Его брат спросил его о том, с кем он ходил вчера на стадион.
9. Больной студент попрочил своего товарища принести из аптеки лекарство.
10. Володя решил, что должен кончить эту работу сегодня.
11. В письме его брат написал о том, чтобы он купил и прислал ему новые марки.

Подробнее - на Znanija.com - https://znanija.com/task/37738481#readmore

Answer (score 2):

1. Друг спросил меня, что я делал вчера вечером. Я ответил, что вчера вечером я ходил в кино.
2. Преподаватель сообщил нам, что послезавтра у нас будет контрольная работа. Мы спросили, будет ли контрольная работа  трудной.
3. Товарищ поинтересовался, какую книгу я читаю. Я ответил, что читаю роман Шолохова.
4. Мой друг удивился, почему я так спешу. Я объяснил  ему, что спешу, потому что опаздываю в театр.
5. Незнакомый мужчина на улице спросил меня, как пройти к станции метро Я сказал ему, чтобы он шел прямо, потом налево.
6. Таня спросила меня, скоро ли я пойду обедать.  Я ответил, что пойду обедать через час.
7. Мой друг посоветовал мне, чтобы я посмотрел  новый фильм.
8. Брат спросил меня, с кем я ходил на стадион.
9. Больной студент попросил товарища, чтобы он принес ему  из аптеки лекарство.
10. Володя решил, что  он должен закончить эту работу сегодня.
11. В письме брат написал мне, чтобы я купил и прислал ему новые марки.

**Пояснение**

В ССП с придаточными **изъяснительными** предложениями (**косвенная речь**) применяются союзы ЧТО (нейтральный), ЧТОБЫ (ирреальный: просьба, желание), частица ЛИ (вопросительная прямая речь),  а также союзные слова КАК, С КЕМ и т.д. (вопросительные местоимения из прямой речи).

Указательные слова (попросил ***о том***, чтобы) с глаголами используются редко (они там обычно лишние), но могут применяться в предложениях  с существительными (мысль ***о том***, что).

"Его друг посоветовал ему посмотреть новый фильм". Этот вариант **с инфинитивом** имеет правильную грамматику, но это **не косвенная реч**ь.

Comment: Исправьте, пожалуйста, 2 предложение.

Comment: Спасибо, исправлено.